# PC is not accessible using Hostname but IP

Tags: dns, active-directory, ip, hostname

The other day I was trying to RDC from my work laptop to work desktop using my PC's hostname but it could find the desktop. Later on I tried with my desktop's IP which worked. Both the time I was on premise and was connected to the network physically.
I could RDC every other computer in our network.

After my research, I checked firewall was disabled, flushed and re-registered dns etc. Everything seems to be in order. However, when I tried to do reverse DNS lookup it didnt work for my desktop.

After that my IT guy and I checked everything on the AD server and there was no entry for my hostname or the IP. So we manually added the dns record which didnt work either.

Following is the note from IT:

> AD / DHCP on a server on a different subnet DNS on another server on
>   the above subnet
>
> The Pc is on a VLAN again different subnet.  The Cisco Switch controls
>   the VLAN but talks to DHCP server for scope
>
> Even adding the A host on forward lookup manually can’t resolve using
>   hostname for ping / mstsc. Both work for IP so deff DNS issue.
>
> Tried to ipconfig /release and renew after giving a different PC the
>   IP address that was originally assigned to this one thinking it would
>   force DNS to update.
>
> There is no entry for the IP or the Hostname in DNS even when the IP
>   changed after a renew. The firewall on the PC is off. However there is
>   the entry in the DHCP address lease table.
>
> Tried flushDNS and ReregisterDNS.

If anyone could point me to the right direction here I would be grateful. Also, if you need further information please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: You're better off asking at [Super User](https://superuser.com/) (for general computing questions) or [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com) (for server administration questions). Stack Overflow is for programming questions.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the correct forum for this question.  However, I can point you in the right direction.

Your correct that this is a DNS issue (so it seems).

The entry that is missing is from the host you are trying to reach (not the client that your trying this from).

Make sure all of the systems are using the same DNS servers.  Make sure the DHCP Client Service is running (even if IP address is hard coded) as that is what actually records the the host name and IP address in DNS.

It sounds like you have the routing set up or you would not be able to do it by IP address.

Is the DNS zone in AD set up to allow dynamic updates?  Do you have the domain name being sent out via DHCP?

Windows will (but not always) try to find a host by DNS and will fall back to a broadcast for the PC name.  This might be why it works from one VLAN, and not from another.